# Customised plugin failed to install and activate

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

I am trying to customise a plugin to add some functionality that is not part of the original.

To do this I have copied all the files into a new folder, and renamed all the function prefixes, changed the header of the main php file.

I have tried uploading the files straight to the server for activation but it was not picked up by WP so I zipped all the files to install them "properly" and it came up with the following output:

> Unpacking the package…
>
> Installing the plugin…
>
> The package could not be installed. No valid plugins were found.
>
> Plugin install failed.
>
> *http://www.mydomain.com/wp-admin/update.php?action=upload-plugin*

Thinking that this may be a header problem I double checked my header but it all appeared to be correct, to my eyes at least.

```
/*
Plugin Name: MC Investment Custom
Plugin URI: http://www.spectra-info.com/wp/plugins (Original)
Description: Customised plugin based on the MC Investment Plugin.
Version: 1.0
Author: Edited by Joshua Ward Original by Spectrain
Author URI: http://www.spectra-info.com (Original)
*/
```

But alas, no success. The .zip file has the plugin file in it's 'root' directory so I am fairly confident that is not the problem.

Is there anything wrong with the plugin header that I can't see? I have tried it without the `(Original)` in the URI lines thinking that was what has mucked it but it appears not.

EDIT: Please stop replacing Customise with Customize. Everybody who types English who is not American, ie me, spell it the British (read: proper) way.

Comment: Have you tried disabling all plugin's and then try to activate?

Comment: Yeah. When I upload it manually it doesn't appear in the plugins list as a deactivated plugin. So it isn't registering as anything to activate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unsure of what I did but it seems to be working now. It may have something to do with the fact that I renamed the main php file to try and avoid a conflict. If I keep it the same file name it "registers".

Comment: what main php are you referring to?